# Prove that $\angle OQE =90 ^{\circ} \Leftrightarrow QE=QF$

Tags: geometry

[image: pic]

> $AN$ is the angle bisector of $BAC$. $P$ is a point on line $AB$ and $O$ is a point on line $AC$, which satisfies that $\angle ANP = 90^{\circ} = \angle APO$. Q is a point on line $NP$. Q is on line $EF$. E is on line $AB$, and F is on line $AC$. Then prove that $\angle OQE =90 ^{\circ} \Leftrightarrow QE=QF$.

My approach.

I proved that $\angle OQE =90 ^{\circ} \Rightarrow QE=QF$.

> $\angle EPO=\angle EQO=90^{\circ} \Rightarrow EPQO$ cyclic.
> $\angle QEO=\angle QPO=\angle NPO=90^{\circ}-\angle NOP=90^{\circ}-\angle AOP=\angle OAP$
>
> Let $X:=PN\cap AC$.
>
> $PAN \equiv XAN$, so $AP=AX$.
>
> $\therefore PAO \equiv XAO$
>
> $\therefore \angle AXO = 90^{\circ}$
>
> $\therefore APOX, QOXF$ cyclic
>
> $\angle QFO = \angle QXO = \angle PXO = \angle PAO$
>
> $\therefore \angle QEO = \angle QFO$
>
> $\angle OQE=90^{\circ}$, so $QE=QF$.

What should I do to prove $\angle OQE =90 ^{\circ} \Leftarrow QE=QF$?

Maybe we can use the method of indetification.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that there is only one line $EF$ which satisfies $QE=QF$.

> Contradiction) Let $E, E'$ and $F, F'$ points on $AB$, $AC$ which satisfies $QE=QF$, $QE'=QF'$.
>
> Then obviously, $\triangle QEE' \equiv \triangle QFF' $ (SAS).
>
> So $\angle QEE'=\angle QFF'$.
>
> So $AB \parallel AC$, and it is a contradiction.

So there is only one pair of $(E, F)$. By method of indetification, proof ends.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to prove quadrilateral $AEOF$ is concyclic.

Because $∠EPO=∠EQO=90˚$, quadrilateral $EOQP$ is noncyclic.

Thus $∠QEO=QPO$.

And also because $∠QPO+∠PON=∠PON+∠PAO=90˚$, $∠QPO=∠PAO=∠OAF$,

therefore $∠QEO=∠OAF$, and quadrilateral $AEOF$ is concyclic.

Hence, $∠EFO=∠EAO=∠OAF=∠EOF$, $EO=FO$, together with $OQ⊥EF$, $QE=QF$ is shown.

Comment: The problem I asked is the opposite of you solved.